# Error: No previous prototype for ‘__sputc’

Tags: macos, avconv, gnutls

I am working on installing avconv for a project I am working on.  I have been using [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/568464/install-latest-libav-avconv-on-osx) on installing avconv on OSX and [this one](https://gist.github.com/morgant/1753095) on building Gnutls for OSX to guide me through this.  Gnutls seems to now be successfully installed but when I attempt to `make` and then `sudo make install` for installing avconv I get the following error:

```
CC  libavdevice/alldevices.o
In file included from ./libavformat/avformat.h:254,
                 from libavdevice/alldevices.c:22:
/usr/include/stdio.h:346: error: no previous prototype for ‘__sputc’
make: *** [libavdevice/alldevices.o] Error 1
```

In looking up as much as possible about this error I either find only logs of this error appearing or help related to dealing with this similar problem when working directly with Xcode (which I am not doing - but I do at least have Xcode and the command line tools installed)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an incorrect compiler for this project. Use

```
sudo port select --list gcc
```

to view the available compilers. On my system it looked like this:

```
Available versions for gcc:
    apple-gcc42
    llvm-gcc42
    none (active)
```

and I had to change that to llvm-gcc42 to make the compilation work:

```
sudo port select --set gcc apple-gcc42
Selecting 'llvm-gcc42' for 'gcc' succeeded. 'llvm-gcc42' is now active.
```

Be also aware of the fact that you either have to disable the input device "jack" to make the compilation work, like this:

```
./configure --extra-cflags=-I/opt/local/include --extra-ldflags=-L/opt/local/lib --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-nonfree --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libfreetype --enable-doc --enable-gnutls --enable-shared --disable-indev=jack
```

or apply the patch in https://trac.ffmpeg.org/attachment/ticket/43/ffmpeg-jack-osx.patch to work around the missing semaphore_* type.